# Size of structures when padded in c

Tags: c, structure, padding

```
struct test {
   
    unsigned int x;
    long int y : 33;
    unsigned int z;   
};
```

how do i be sure of the size of this structure. If i reorder the size is different.

Comment: `sizeof(struct test)`

Comment: If you want to test what it is, you can use `sizeof`. If you want to make sure that it's a specific size, you can use `sizeof` in a `static_assert`.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve that depends on the size of the structure?

Comment: If you can possibly avoid it, my recommendation is that you do *not* try to be sure of the size of this structure.  It's a fool's errand, in my opinion.  If the reason you're trying to nail down the size of the structure is so that you can do i/o to/from some externally-imposed storage layout, there are other, easier ways of doing that.

Comment: If you compile for a different device, the size might be different too. The size of the datatype depends on the target machine and the compiler. I live with a 32-bit `long` in 2022, and no `long long`... You've got to know what you're doing...

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the GNU C Manual section [2.4.5 Size of Structures](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Size-of-Structures)

> The size of a structure type is equal to the sum of the size of all of its members, possibly including padding to cause the structure type to align to a particular byte boundary. The details vary depending on your computer platform, but it would not be atypical to see structures padded to align on four- or eight-byte boundaries. This is done in order to speed up memory accesses of instances of the structure type.

This means that the padding value, the compile optimisation result and the type bit-length is platform dependent.

You will need to give further details, and to audit the size of each of your defined types in order to be able of being sure.

This is an example code and its output :

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                    
                                                                                      
typedef struct s_test {                                                               
                                                                                      
    unsigned int x;                                                                   
    long int y : 33;                                                                  
    unsigned int z;                                                                   
} test;                                                                               
                                                                                      
int main() {                                                                          
  printf("Unsigned int size : %d\n", sizeof(unsigned int));                           
  printf("Long int size : %d\n", sizeof(long int));                                   
  printf("Total size : %d\n", sizeof(test));                                          
}
```

```
OUTPUT :
Unsigned int size : 4
Long int size : 8
Total size : 24
```

Supposing my system is doing a 8-bit padding, I rearrange the struct this way :

```
typedef struct s_test {                                                               
  long int y : 33;                                                                    
  unsigned int x;                                                                     
  unsigned int z;                                                                     
} test;
```

The expected result is around 16 bits. And this is my final output :

```
OUTPUT :
Unsigned int size : 4
Long int size : 8
Total size : 16
```

As I said before you can't really base your optimisation on the result on your machine, since the result will be different for more complex types and different computers.

EDIT : As mentionned in comments, you can check *at compile time* the size of your structure with a [`static_assert` call](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Static_assert) but I personnaly don't recommend it for the same reasons as above.